# How to configure config.json so that batch contacts gets processed?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity, custom-event

I am designing a journey builder custom activity. The official documentation says
execute - The API calls this method for each contact processed by the journey.

However I want to to configure inArguments in such a way that one request contains multiple contact details.

```
"arguments": {
"execute": {
  "inArguments": [
    {
      "emailAddress": "{{InteractionDefaults.Email}}"
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "{{Contact.Default.PhoneNumber}}"
    }
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't work in Batch Mode as per the current architecture.
Even I had the similar requirement and I have used Microsoft resources and there are many ways to batch up.

below is what I did,

- Use Messaging Queue like  [ASB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions) or [IronMQ](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/iron_mq) based on system you use for Hosting your webapp.
- Use Batch Processor like [Logic App](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-batch-process-send-receive-messages) or Mulesoft Connector to concatenate and send 1 API call
- Point your config.json execute API to above ASB Queue endpoint